# jQuery - loading form(s), submitting POST, retrieving result without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

First off, I have extensively researched this, and have been unable to successfully apply any of the answers I've found, at least in the way that I want. I think I'm close, but I may be way off...

A similar question was asked here: [Submit form in div with ajax, return php in div without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993112/submit-form-in-div-with-ajax-return-php-in-div-without-refresh?rq=1)

I am essentially working with 4 divs, div 1 offers a choice of adding, editing, or dropping users. div 2 is a new row in the container, When you select Add, the file loaded creates 2 columns inside the row (both separate divs), the first (div 3) with a drop-down menu asking how many users you want to add. The answer is sent to another PHP file which uses a FOR loop to create the right number of forms, and is supposed to then load them into div 4 (which is id'd as 'forms' at the end of the included code).

The PHP all works fine, and loading the initial drop-down into div 2 works, but every time I hit submit, it does nothing and erases the whole row (which includes the drop-down (div 3 with the drop-down, and div 4 for the forms). If I change the action on the 'num' form to the actual php file, it loads the forms on a new page, instead of in the target div...here's what I think is the relevant code.

**controls.php**

```
<?php 

require_once 'header.php';

if ($loggedin == true && ($user->roles == 1 || $user->roles == 2)) {
echo <<<_END

<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script>    

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addUsr').click(function(){
        $('#controls').load('add.php', function(){
        });
    });

    $('#editUsr').click(function(){
        $('#controls').load('edit.php', function(){
        });
    });

    $('#updateUsr').click(function(){
        $('#controls').load('update.php', function(){
        });
    });     
});     

</script>
<hr class='small-divider'></hr>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-8'>
 <h2>Welcome to the User Control Panel</h2>
 <p>To use this feature, please choose from the options to the right, and the appropriate form will appear below.</p>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4' id='ctrlwho'>

 <h4>What do you want to do?</h4>
 <p><button class='btn btn-md btn-primary' id='addUsr' type='button'>Add new</button></p>
 <p><button class='btn btn-md btn-primary' id='editUsr' type='button'>Edit current</button></p>
 <p><button class='btn btn-md btn-primary' id='updateUser' type='button'>Update Oficers and Committee Heads</button></p>
 </div>
</div>  
<div class='row' id='controls'>

</div>
</div>



_END;

}
?>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php

echo <<<_END

<script>
  $("#num").submit(function(){

   $.ajax({
    url: 'add.forms.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#num").serialize(),         
     success: function(data) {
      $("#forms").empty();
      $("#forms").append(data);
     }
    });
    return false;       
  });
</script>
<div class='col-md-3' id='numForm'> // ineloquently called div-3 in my post
<p>How many users do you want to add?</p>
<p><form name='num' id='num' method='POST' action=''>
<select name='number' size='1' id='select-1'>
 <option value=1>1</option>
 <option value=2>2</option>
 <option value=3>3</option>
 <option value=4>4</option>
 <option value=5>5</option>
 <option value=10>10</option>
 <option value=15>15</option>
 <option value=20>20</option>
 <option value=30>30</option>
 <option value=50>50</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='This Many' />
</form>
</div>
<div class='col-md-9' id='forms'> </div> // ineloquently called div-4 above
_END;
?>
```

I imagine it's something relatively simple, but it seems ridiculous to keep struggling with it when there's such a great resource available here. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try passing `event` argument inside click and use `preventDefault()`  ex. `$('#addUsr').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Side note, $loggedin = true should be $loggedin === true in your controls file

Comment: mjayt - From what I know, === is pretty much "if and only if $x = exactly y"? Why does using a single '=' cause a weakness? And how would it be exploited?

Comment: See my answer below... your if is completely broken. You are assigning instead of comparing and your or is wrong. It is only working because you are just setting two values that technically evaluate to true. I'll delete the answer as it is a side note to your question, but that if is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: mjayt - Thank you. I am not sure how I didn't realize the =/== issue. I believe I've gotten it straightened out now, but maybe it's still working because it's so broken somewhere else. We'll see. I'm sure I'll be back...

Comment: Good luck, fixing the problems is the best way to get better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but:

You should get rid of the last parenthesis on this line:

```
$("#num").submit(function()({
```

It should just be:

```
$("#num").submit(function(){
```

Comment: Wow, after all that, it was a stupid parentheses...Hah. Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: I edited my code above to reflect this, so hopefully future searchers can use it as a useful reference...